# carrierwave: mount uploader at a virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, carrierwave, uploader

I'm using a more or less generic property model with the two attributes :key and :value. The value is a string attributes which can be used as uploader dependent on the parent object. How can I mount the uploader beside using the property as normal string attribute? I tried to create something like this:

```
def imagelink 
  self.value
end

def imagelink=(value)
 self.value=value
end

mount_uploader :imagelink, MyUploaderClass
```

But this ends up in an active_record error because the imagelink-property is not a real active_record attribute?

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to do this?

Comment: I have a key-value-pair table which is more or less a generic way to store dynamic properties of my objects. The user can create a property and can store values to this. The property can be a file for this I use the :reslink property or the value can be an image file and I want to ensure that I use two different uploaders for images and normal files because carrierwave generates thumbs for images.

Answer (score 0):

while experimenting with the rails_admin gem i had to make several other attributes accessible, to get the generic upload functionality to work, :img_small_cache and :remove_img_small where virtual attributes too because only :img_small stored the filestring in the db

```
mount_uploader :img_small, ProductImgSmallUploader
attr_accessible :img_small, :img_small_cache, :remove_img_small
```

maybe it helps to find an answer